# React Native - Infinity Loop When Swipe to Refresh of Container and FlatList

Tags: node.js, react-native, native-base

I get a problem , look to my code :

```
...
...
async onRefresh() {
        this.setState({ loadingFlatList: true });
        Alert.alert(
            'Error',
            "Refresheeeedd ....",
            [
                {text: 'OK', onPress: () =>  null },
            ],
            {cancelable: false}
        )
    }
<Content refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.loadingFlatList} onRefresh={this.onRefresh()} />} padder style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} >
                    <Loader
                        loading={this.state.loading} />

                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.listViewData}
                        // data={[{key: '1'}, {key: '2'}, {key: '3'}, {key: '4'}, {key: '5'}]}
                        // contentContainerStyle={customers.length === 0 && styles.centerEmptySet}
                        renderItem={({item}) =>
...
...
```

> When i run the code above. It show alert multiple time (never end) of
>   the onRefresh function. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `this.onRefresh` when you are defining `<RefreshControl` componet.

```
<Content refreshControl={<RefreshControl ... onRefresh={this.onRefresh()} />} ... />
```

Instead, pass the reference of the function

```
<Content refreshControl={<RefreshControl ... onRefresh={this.onRefresh} />} ... />
```

Try with above change, hope this will help!